# "Knocked out of the box"

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Sylvia Plath has knocked Keats out of the box.

I am confused with its meaning. *Keats* is a famous poet in England, but who is *Sylvia Plath*? Is this sentence a slang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence is from Roger Angell’s “Foreword” to the latest edition of *Elements of Style*, whose principal author, E.B. White, was Angell’s stepfather.

Keats (1795-1921) is a famous English poet of the second generation of Romantics. Sylvia Plath (1932-1963) is an equally famous American poet. Angell is discussing changes in the new edition, and pointing out that in a sentence about “those modern poets who died young” the original “Keats” has been replaced with “Plath”.

Angell has been for forty or fifty years the most widely admired writer on baseball, and the idiom he employs to describe Keats’ replacement by Plath is drawn from that sport. A pitcher is said to have been “knocked out of the box” when batters hit his pitches so effectively that he is compelled to give way to another pitcher. The expression arose in the 19th century, when the area from which the pitcher threw was marked by a ‘box’ marked with chalk lines. The box has since been replaced by a low mound, but the expression has remained.

---

ADDED:
In a comment, OP asks for an explanation of the remainder of Angell’s sentence

> Sylvia Plath has knocked Keats out of the box, and I notice that “America” has become “this country” in a sample text, to forestall a subsequent and possibly demeaning “she” in the same paragraph.

Angell misquotes slightly (and trivially). In a discussion of how to use *but* White originally recommended rewriting

> America had vast resources, but she seemed almost wholly unprepared for war. But within a year she had created an army of four million men.

as

> America seemed almost wholly unprepared for war, but she had vast resources. Within a year she had created an army of four million men.

In the edition Angell introduces these two passages have become

> Our country had vast resources but seemed almost wholly unprepared for war. But within a year it had created an army of four million.

and

> Our country seemed almost wholly unprepared for war, but it had vast resources. Within a year it had created an army of four million.

Angell is noting that the change from *America ... she* to *Our country ... it* was apparently motivated by the desire to avoid sexist language. This is of a piece with the replacement of Keats by Plath—the paragraph begins

> This edition has been modestly updated […] with a light redistribution of genders to permit a feminine pronoun or female farmer to take their places among the males who once innocently served [White].

Comment: *Sylvia Plath has knocked Keats out of the box, and I notice that "American" has become "this country" in a sample text, to forestall a subsequent and possibly demeaning "she" in the same paragraph.* Above is the sentence in the book you have said. However what is the meaning or function in the context?

Comment: @gaoxinge Is my addition what you were looking for?

Comment: @gaoxinge - I believe the "meaning or function in context" is simply: "In this newer edition, some poems written by Plath have replaced some poems written by Keats that were found in our previous edition."